# typecasting adjacency_iterator to vertex_iterator in C++ boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost

I have `std::queue<boost::adjacency_list<>::vertex_iterator> q;`
into which I will be pushing the adjacent vertices of a Node in a graph.

I need to pop elements from this list and use them as `vertex_iterators`.

Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. What is the problem? What is the question? Of course if you have a `queue<T>` you can pop `T`s and use them as a `T`.